# Could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a hql to show my data based on between(to_date), but i got `Could not locate named parameter` error

this is my code

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String tgl1 = sdf1.format(date1);
    String Tanggal_awal = tgl1+" 00:00:00";
    System.out.println(Tanggal_awal);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String tgl2 = sdf2.format(date2);
    String Tanggal_akhir = tgl2+" 23:59:59";
    System.out.println(Tanggal_akhir);

    Query LoadSource = session_source.createQuery("select CLIENT,SERVICE,SERVICE_TYPE,PROVIDER_CODE,COUNT(*) FROM SwitcherServiceSource" +
            " where TIMESTAMP between to_date(':awal','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and to_date(':akhir','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')" +
            " and PROVIDER_CODE is not null group by CLIENT,SERVICE,SERVICE_TYPE,PROVIDER_CODE order by CLIENT,SERVICE,SERVICE_TYPE,PROVIDER_CODE");
    LoadSource.setParameter("awal", Tanggal_awal);
    LoadSource.setParameter("akhir", Tanggal_akhir);
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to quote your parameters. i.e.:

Instead of having `where TIMESTAMP between to_date(':awal','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and to_date(':akhir','dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')`, you should write `where TIMESTAMP between to_date(:awal,'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and to_date(:akhir,'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')`

---

And even better, you can (and you should) even avoid binding a string to that parameter.  You can bind a Date/Timestamp, so that the query is even more effective and readable:  `where TIMESTAMP between :awal and :akhir`, and do something similar to this in your code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Date fromDate = cal.getTime();

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

Date toDate = cal.getTime();

Query loadSource = session_source.createQuery("select blablabla FROM SwitcherServiceSource" +
        " where TIMESTAMP between :awal and :akhir " +
        " and blablabla group by blabla order by blablabla");
loadSource.setParameter("awal", fromDate );
loadSource.setParameter("akhir", toDate);
```